# mySQL Select All where date is less than 1 day from max date in data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a table name "raw".
The date column is not having all the dates of month as it does not record holidays or when there were no sales for the day.
I am trying to get the data form the date less than a day of specific date or max date but it is not returning the search as before the max date was holiday.
here are the dates:
2021-07-09
2021-07-07
2021-07-03
2021-07-02
2021-07-01
2021-06-30

```
SELECT *
    FROM raw
    WHERE date=(SELECT MAX(date) - 1 FROM raw);

or

SELECT *
FROM raw
WHERE date=(SELECT MAX(date) - interval 1 day FROM raw);

    \begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Name  & Date       & Sales \\
ACC   & 2020-07-09 & 2000  \\
BEL   & 2020-07-09 & 200   \\
Dabur & 2020-07-09 & 600   \\
ACC   & 2020-07-07 & 450   \\
GMR   & 2020-07-07 & 12    \\
ACC   & 2020-07-03 & 450   \\
ITC   & 2020-07-03 & 45    \\
Dabur & 2020-07-03 & 350   \\
GMR   & 2020-07-03 & 450   \\
BEL   & 2020-06-30 & 500   \\
GTL   & 2020-06-30 & 850   \\
Dabur & 2020-06-30 & 100   \\
ACC   & 2020-06-27 & 50    \\
Dabur & 2020-06-27 & 125  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question to make it concrete.

Comment: do you need single record of day less than max date ? Please share the sample output also.

Comment: No, I need all records (rows) related to 2020-07-07. but by decreasing 1 date less method as need to use the function for more data.

Comment: basically I am looking to search data based on available date just previous to max date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the data from the day before a specific date, then use:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM raw r
WHERE r.date = (SELECT MAX(r2.date) FROM raw r2 WHERE r2.date < ?);
```

The `?` is the specific date.

For the date previous to the maximum date, you could use:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM raw r
WHERE r.date = (SELECT MAX(r2.date)
                FROM raw r2
                WHERE r2.date < (SELECT MAX(r2.date) FROM raw r3)
               );
```

Ouch.  Two levels of subqueries.  That seems cumbersome.  A simpler method is:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM raw r
WHERE r.date = (SELECT DISTINCT r2.date
                FROM raw r2
                ORDER BY r2.DATE DESC
                LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
               );
```

Comment: @Avi . . . Given that your question is both about an arbitrary date and the penultimate date, I'm surprised you didn't accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The query posted by TheWinterCoder should work perfectly if you just change the Order by clause to

```
rank() over ( order by date desc) date_rank
```

However, If that somehow doesn't work, You may try below query -

```
SELECT *
    FROM raw
    WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date)
                    FROM raw
                   WHERE date < (SELECT MAX(date) FROM raw));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have breaks in your dates, you can't just subtract 1 from the max date. You would need to rank the dates and then select the top two ranks.

[This should help](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/) and your query will look something like this:

```
with order_dates AS(
      Select *,
             dense_rank() over ( order by date desc) date_rank
      from raw
)
select *
from order_dates
where date_rank <=2
```

Comment: its showing entries from 1st date that is 08-06-2020

Comment: you can add asc or desc to the order by part to change the way your order them i.e. (order by date desc)

Comment: hi
already tried that buy it is ranking with the interval of 7 like
1 8 15 22
so I am not able to find rank 2

Comment: ah apologises, swap rank() for dense_rank() should then make it so there is no gaps between ranking numbers. I'll update my original answer